# Python comparing two massive sets of data in the MOST efficient method possible

Tags: python, database, diff, set, compare

I have to compare massive database dumps in xls format to parse for changes day-to-day (gross, right?). I'm currently doing this in the most backwards way possible, and using xlrd to turn the xls into csv files, and then I'm running diffs to compare them.

Since it's a database, and I don't have a means of knowing if the data ever stays in the same order after something like an item deletion, I can't do a compare x line to x line between the files, so doing lists of tuples or something wouldn't make the most sense to me.

I basically need to find every single change that could have happened on any row REGARDLESS of that row's position in the actual dump, and the only real "lookup" I could think of is SKU as a unique ID (it's a product table from an ancient DB system), but I need to know a lot more than just products being deleted or added, because they could modify pricing or anything else in that item.

Should I be using sets? And once I've loaded 75+ thousand lines of this database file into a "set", is my ram usage going to be hysterical?

I thought about loading in each row of the xls as a big concatenated string to add to a set. Is that an efficient idea? I could basically get a list of rows that differ between sets and then go back after those rows in the original db file to find my actual differences.

I've never worked with data parsing on a scale like this. I'm mostly just looking for any advice to not make this process any more ridiculous than it has to be, and I came here after not really finding something that seemed specific enough to my case to feel like good advice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you haven't even tried it to see what, if any, problems you'll run into. Modern computers are surprisingly powerful. I'd suggest trying it, then coming back with the problems you're facing. The community will be better able to help you with specific problems.

Comment: Could you configure the database to log a record of the changes made? It seems easier than trying to detect changes after-the-fact.

Comment: I'll agree with @Kevin on this one; are there any restrictions on you that would make configuring the database not possible?

Comment: No, it's a legacy system I can't edit.

Comment: Also, this is going to be running on a web server, thus the only reason I care about RAM. Sorry for being unspecific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use sets for exactly that purpose, but try to keep the number of items down to several million at a time. As S.Lott said, 75,000 is nothing. I use a similar system for populating database tables from imported date while only issuing the minimum number of INSERTs and DELETEs required to "patch" the table from the results of the last import. The basic algorithm is along the lines of:

```
lastset = [...]  # Populate with the output of the last run
thisset = [...]  # The current results

# Remove rows that aren't in the current result set
for row in lastset - thisset:
    deleteentry(row[0])  # Where row[0] is the unique key for the table

# Add rows that weren't in the last result set
for row in thisset - lastset:
    insertentry(row)
```

To convince yourself that set operations are quick and sufficiently RAM efficient, try this:

```
>>> a = set(range(10000000))
>>> b = set(range(100, 10000100))
>>> len(a - b)
100
>>> len(b - a)
100
```

That takes about 1.25GB on my Mac. That's a lot of RAM, true, but probably from over 100 times the number of entries you're working with. The set operations run in well under a second here.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I be using sets?

Probably not.  The question is too vague to answer, however.

> And once I've loaded 75+ thousand lines of this database file into a "set", is my ram usage going to be hysterical?

No.  75000 objects isn't much.  This isn't massive.  It's not even close to massive.

Python offers you http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html which can help you create a slightly more optimal algorithm.

Since you're dumping a database, it's better to dump it as a CSV file instead of an XLS file.  CSV files are much, much easier to work with.

Here's brute-force using CSV.

```
import csv
with open('yesterday.csv','rb') as yesterday:
    rdr= csv.DictReader( yesterday )
    baseline= {}
    for row in rdr:
        baseline[ row['key'] ]= row
with open('today.csv', 'rb' ) as today:
    rdr= csv.DictReader( today )
    update= {}
    for row in rdr:
        if baseline[row['key']] == row:
            continue
        # You have a delta
```

Comment: I don't have control over file output. It's a legacy system, and it's awful. Also, your method won't take into account the possible different ordering of materials based on database collapsing around deletion.

Comment: @vapirix: "your method won't take into account the possible different ordering of materials based on database collapsing around deletion"  What?  The keys are the keys.  Missing elements are trivially detected by adding some code to this.  Since your requirements were incomplete the code is incomplete.  You are free to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the data into a database, and compare the databases. If you think that is easier.

The key question you might need to think about is: **can you sort the data somehow**?

Sorted sets are so much easier to handle.

P.S. 75000 lines is *not* very much. Anything that fits into main memory of a regular computer is not much. Add a couple of 0s.